# Route calculation on leaflet GIS?

Tags: leaflet, routing

I know that there are a lot of leaflet extensions that makes the GIS just awsome ; I would like to know if there is a way may be an extension to calculate route path from origine to destination by roads or by bus line.

Comment: There's a whole section in the plugins list: http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#routing

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine) repository on github developed by PerLiedman. On his personal web page there are several [tutorials](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/) and a useful [API](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/).